# jQuery Deferred with jQueryUI/Bootstrap dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-deferred

I have been working on a solution for displaying a conformation dialog for a form submit.

Basicly I wanted to replace the built-in `confirm()` function with myown, so I could write my form as `<form onsubmit="customConfirm()"></form>`. I thourght I could use *promises* for this, so I could prevent the form from submitting, display the dialog, return a promise and then resolve or reject that promise upon click of the the OK and Cancel buttons.

The problem is that my deferred object seems to be ignored,  both the `done` and `fail` functions are called - I have [created a little jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvhttp4x/) that shows what I am talking about.

I must say I haven't worked with promises a lot so maybe I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you intend but this works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/vvhttp4x/1/

```
var dfd = confirmDialog();
dfd.done(function () {
    alert("done");
});
dfd.fail(function () {
    alert("fail");
});
```

It's a promise so if you do `dfd.state()` right away you'll always get `pending`.

You should continue your code in the `done` or `fail` handler.

Comment: Thansk, that was quick! This lead me to find the answer, I neede to wrap my `done` and `fail` function calls in annoynomous functions

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Halcyon lead me to find the answer.

I needed to wrap my `done` and `fail` function calls inside annoynomous functions.

```
    var name = "Billy";
    var dfd = confirmDialog();
    $.when(
        dfd
    ).then(function() {
            alert('Hello there ' + name)
           },function() {
            alert('Goodbye ' + name)
    });
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvhttp4x/2/)